# How hibernate generates queries?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am extremely curious to know how hibernate generates queries. I have looked at multiple website, but all tell me how to use HQL. I want to know how internally hibernate generates the queries. I want to build a query generator of my own. I am having difficulty in writing the logic for building queries, which can be generated in multiple ways and have various syntax and complexities. I know that hibernate translates the HQL into queries. I can also see how the queries are building in the logs. I want to know the mechanism they use to generate these queries. Like is there a fixed format or XSD in which they store the queries. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hibernate is open source. You can download all the source code and find out yourself how it generates queries. If you have a specific, directed question about it, then you can, after you have made some effort into researching it, ask about it here.

Comment: Can I at-least know why this question is getting down voted. I did search many places (including stackoverflow) and did not find an answer.

Comment: Ok.. I am doing the same now. Thanks @Erwin. Still it would be great if anyone can shed some light on the internal mechanism involved.

Comment: @GouravmoyMohanty, did you found any useful docs?